# Find ranges of grouped numbers (log n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, binary-search

Assume an array of grouped numbers:

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

I want to find the range for each number, assuming that all numbers are grouped together in the input array. The output should be:

```
1: (0,5)
2: (6,10)
3: (11,14)
8: (15,19)
4: (20,23)
```

I applied an alteration of binary search, but the output I'm getting is erronous.

**I'm looking for a solution with log(n) Time complexity**

*This is a simplified version of a problem I'm dealing with building an ETL pipeline where visiting an element requires downloading a 100gb file.*

Comment: It's not possible to do this in worst-case logarithmic time unless there are additional constraints on the input that you haven't mentioned. (For example, suppose that every range has length one. Then you'll need to examine all *n* elements and return *n* ranges.)

Comment: Is `arr` sorted? Binary search assumes that the input is sorted.

Comment: @ruakh getting O(n) in worst case is fine, stability is not a hard constraint. I think it's possible to reach this at log(n) because the numbers are grouped together.

Comment: @NickODell `arr` is not sorted - I used the idea of binary search as in dividing the interval in half, and dividing a sub interval only if the midpoint is different than its endpoint.

Comment: @NickODell: The definition of "sorted" can be flexible. The OP's array seems to have the property that all occurrences of a given value occur in a single contiguous "range". So given a certain index `i`, you can use binary search to find the end of the "range" containing `arr[i]`, by considering all values other than `arr[i]` to be "greater than" `arr[i]`.

Comment: @NickODell: Or, probably a better way to phrase my previous comment: Binary search requires some way to distinguish an index *before* the one you're interested in from an index *after* the one you're interested in. In the classic case, that involves a sorted array where you're searching for an element by value, but it can be applied to a case like this where we want to find the end of a range, and can distinguish "still in same range" from "after end of range" by checking if the values match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a solution with log(n) Time complexity

That's not possible in the general case; the best you can do is *O*(*r* + log *n*) time, or (equivalently) *O*(*MAX*(*r*, log *n*)) time, where *r* is the number of ranges. (This is because you need to build the list of *r* ranges in order to return it, and you can't do that in less than *Θ*(*r*) time.)

> I used the idea of binary search as in dividing the interval in half, and dividing a sub interval only if the midpoint is different than its endpoint.

That's roughly the right approach, but the devil is in the details.

What I'd suggest is doing *r* separate binary searches — one for each range, from left to right — *but* using a stack to keep track of values that you've previously fetched but are further right than the current range. You can use that stack to quickly find initial 'lo' and 'hi' values for the binary search. That way, you can achieve the asymptotically optimal *O*(*r* + log *n*) worst-case time.

Here's a JavaScript implementation of that concept:

```js
function doIt(arr) {
  const stack = [];
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    stack.push({ pos: arr.length - 1, val: arr[arr.length - 1] });
  }
  stack.push({ pos: 0, val: arr[0] });

  const result = [];

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const start = stack.pop();

    let lo = start.pos;
    while (stack.length > 0 && stack.at(-1).val === start.val) {
      lo = stack.pop().pos;
    }

    if (stack.length > 0) {
      while (true) {
        const hi = stack.at(-1).pos;

        if (lo + 1 === hi) {
          break;
        }

        const midPos = Math.trunc(lo + (hi - lo) / 2);
        const midVal = arr[midPos];
        if (midVal === start.val) {
          lo = midPos;
        } else {
          stack.push({ pos: midPos, val: midVal });
        }
      }
    }

    result.push({ start: start.pos, end: lo, val: start.val });
  }

  return result;
}

const arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4];

console.log(JSON.stringify(doIt(arr)));
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution is much more elegant and relatively stable than what I had sketched. Works like a charm. I appreciate your time!