# Given a really large sorted integer array find out all the elements that are power of 2

Tags: algorithm

I was asked an interview question where the problem statement is like below. I was wondering if there is any efficient solution to this.

Given a really large sorted integer array with no duplicates, find out all the elements that are power of 2.

My solution:

Run a loop for whole array and find out elements where log(n)/log(2) is integer.

Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(1)

Comment: Re: "find out elements where log(n)/log(2) is integer": FYI, a *much* more efficient way to check if an integer `n` is a power of two is `n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0`. But that's not what your interviewer was looking for!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77813454/978917

Comment: In the worst case the complexity cannot be any less than that, because all numbers in the array could be powers of two. But if the range of the integer is limited, we can do better.

Comment: Numbers are stored in binary in the computer, which means for the computer, recognising powers of 2 is a simple as for a human it is to recognise powers of 10. They're numbers of the form 1000000, a 1 followed by any number of zeroes. So checking whether log(n)/log(2) is an integer is not the most straightforward way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is sorted, you can use binary search to find any given value.

If by "integer array" we mean that its elements are fixed-width integers — say, 32-bit integers or 64-bit integers — then it's actually reasonably efficient to simply iterate over all representable powers of two and do a binary search for each:

```java
public static long[] findPowersOfTwo(final long[] arr) {
  final long[] result = new long[63];
  int resultIndex = 0;
  for (int exp = 0; exp < 63; ++exp) {
    final long pow = (1L << exp);
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length;
    while (lo + 1 < hi) {
      final int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
      final long val = arr[mid];
      if (val <= pow) {
        lo = mid;
      } else {
        hi = mid;
      }
    }
    if (arr[lo] == pow) {
      result[resultIndex++] = pow;
    }
  }
  return Arrays.copyOf(result, resultIndex);
}
```

A more sophisticated approach is to recursively examine the two halves of the array, but skipping any section where we know that there are no powers of two.

How might we know that a given section of the array can't contain any powers of two? Well, if the first and last elements of the section have their highest '1' bits in the same position, then there can't be any powers of two in that section, except for possibly the first element.

So, two convenient bit-twiddling hacks:

- a positive integer `i` is a power of two if `(i & (i - 1)) == 0`
- positive integers `i` and `j`, with `j > i`, have their highest '1' bits in the same position if and only if `(i & j) > j / 2`.

(It may seem like I've pulled those out of a magic hat, but if you write out some different cases in binary and try them out, you'll see why.)

Given the above facts, we can write:

```java
public static long[] findPowersOfTwo(final long[] arr) {
  // need to find the first positive integer, because our
  // 'help' method uses bit-twiddling hacks that get confused
  // by negative integers and zero:
  final long[] result = new long[64];
  final int resultIndex =
    help(result, 0, arr, findFirstPositive(arr), arr.length);
  return Arrays.copyOf(result, resultIndex);
}

private static int findFirstPositive(final long[] arr) {
  int lo = -1;
  int hi = arr.length - 1;
  while (lo + 1 < hi) {
    final int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] <= 0) {
      lo = mid;
    } else {
      hi = mid;
    }
  }
  return hi;
}

private static int help(
  final long[] result,
  int resultIndex,
  final long[] arr,
  final int start,
  final int end
) {
  if (start >= end) {
    return resultIndex;
  }

  final long firstVal = arr[start];
  if ((firstVal & (firstVal - 1)) == 0) {
    result[resultIndex++] = firstVal;
  }

  final long lastVal = arr[end - 1];
  if ((firstVal & lastVal) > lastVal / 2) {
    return resultIndex;
  }

  // if we're here, then we know that end - 1 > start

  final int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
  resultIndex = help(result, resultIndex, arr, start + 1, mid);
  return help(result, resultIndex, arr, mid, end);
}
```

That said, I've just tried this out (with an array of ten million randomly-generated 64-bit integers of which ten were randomly-generated powers of two), and it was only about twice as fast as just doing 63 binary searches. Which is better, obviously, but I'd hoped for an even bigger difference.

But either of these approaches performs *far* better than simply iterating over the array and checking each element, even if you use `i > 0 && (i & (i - 1)) == 0` to test elements. I found in my testing that the iteration approach took 50 to 100 times as long as either of the approaches above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the exact question on that but I can give my few cents to that task.

As it has already been stated in the comments this is the most optimal way you find if n is power of two `n > 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0`

Imagine you are not so good at math or you cant use bitwise operations you can go for different approach.

First of all - the array is sorted. I will assume that it is from smallest to largest, but it should be the same if it is from largest to smallest. You will just iterate from n-1 to 0.

As the array is sorted this mean that you can always store in a variable the next power of two that can possibly be in the array. And once the current element is bigger than it, increase the value until it is bigger again. Sth like that. On every iteration you check if the "next pow" is equals to the current element.

See the pseudocode below to acquire better perspective:

```
unsigned int powerOfTwo = 1;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   if(a[i] <= 0) 
   {
      continue;
   }

   if(powerOfTwo > arr[i]) 
   {
      continue;
   }

   if(powerOfTwo == arr[i]) 
   {
      // print, add to array, increase counter or whatever you need to do
      // don't increase the power of two for now as the next element might have the same value
      continue;
   }
  
   if(powerOfTwo < arr[i]) // if statement added for clarity, to this point it obviously will be smaller
   {
      while(powerOfTwo < arr[i]) //increase untill powerOfTwo catches up on the values in the array
      {
         powerOfTwo *= 2;
      }

      if(powerOfTwo == arr[i]) 
      {
         // print, add to array, increase counter or whatever you need to do
         // don't increase the power of two for now as the next element might have the same value
         continue;
      }

   }
}
```

note: it will require a little more iterations than N, but according the O notation this still will be O(n) time solution and O(1) memory

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do better than O(), as the input might consist of only values that are powers of 2, and then all of them should be returned. But this would mean the values in the total range of integers are not distributed *evenly*. If it is expected that the values are distributed *evenly* (like if the first 100 values span a range of 5000, then it is expected the next 100 values would also span a range of the same order of magnitude), then we can get an average time complexity of O(log²) -- if we assume O(1) for arithmetic operations:

We can look at the first and last value in the (already sorted) array and derive from that the least and greatest power of 2 that fall in that range. We thus have a list of O(log) powers of 2 that could potentially be present in the array.

Then for each we could execute a binary search to find that power. We can gain some execution time by starting with the greatest power, as the index we get from the binary search will reduce the window for the next binary search significantly. On average the window will be *halved* on each iteration over the powers of 2 (again, if we assume an even distribution). However, this gain does not influence the overal time complexity, which is O(log²).

Here is an implementation of that idea in a runnable JavaScript snippet. As a demo, the function is ran with an input of a million sorted values, evenly distributed.

```js
function binarySearch(sorted, value, start, end) {
    while (start < end) {
        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        if (value > sorted[mid]) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    return end;
}

function findPowers(sorted) {
    let end = sorted.length;
    let start = binarySearch(sorted, 1, 0, end); // Exclude non-positives
    if (start >= end) return []; // No positives
    let minExp = Math.ceil(Math.log2(sorted[start]));
    let maxExp = Math.floor(Math.log2(sorted[end-1]));
    const powers = [];
    // By using a decreasing order we expect to better reduce the search-window
    for (let exp = maxExp; exp >= minExp; exp--) { // O(logn) iterations
        let value = 2 ** exp; // Value to be found
        end = binarySearch(sorted, value, start, end);
        if (sorted[end] === value) powers.push(value);
    }
    return powers.reverse(); // Possibly we want them in increasing order
}

// Test with array having a million homogeneously distributed integers
const sorted = Array.from({length: 1e6}, (_, i) => i * 7 + i % 6 - 8);
const powers = findPowers(sorted);
console.log(...powers);
```

NB: the above complexity analysis assumes constant running times for arithmetic operations. If instead we would use the [Computational complexity of mathematical operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations), then if the largest number in the input is , the arithmetic operations in the binary search loop (addition, division by 2, comparison) would add a factor to the overal complexity, making it O(log log²).

Comment: Worst case if all the elements are powers of two means you have to return that information but it could be returned as a list of powers of two and their frequency counts which could be done much faster. Essentially divide and conquer by looking at the maximum element Ymax picking 2^N just above that value and cutting the array into two at (N odd 2^((N+1)/2, even 2^(N/2)) and applying the same search strategy to divide and conquer. That will find any solid blocks of identical 2^N numbers in log(N) time and can potentially ignore big chunks at the high values end of the array.

Comment: @MartinBrown, *"but it could be returned as a list of powers of two and their frequency counts which could be done much faster"*: it is given that all values are unique. *"That will find any solid blocks of identical 2^N numbers in log(N) time"*: if these blocks have size 1, and you have O(N) of them, then it would not be O(logN).

Comment: @MartinBrown, BTW, if you think you have a good solution, then please post an answer.